# Azure Managed Application

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

Is there any extensibility/functionality in Azure Managed Applications to publish a custom administration UI (used by the customer after the deployment of the Managed Application to their tenant)? I'm looking to basically expose a custom admin UI embedded in the Azure management portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways a managed application authors can customize their UX:

1. CreateUIDefinition: This is a mandatory file that is part of the managed app package that customizes the customer's onboarding experience. You can utilize different controls we've made available to take whatever input needed from the customer to be used within the mainTemplate.json for deploying the application resources.

o   [Creating CreateUIDef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/create-uidefinition-overview)

o   [Testing CreateUIDef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/test-createuidefinition)

2. Custom Actions & ViewDefinition: Managed Applications can utilize another resource called an Azure Custom Provider that allows them to define custom actions that can be taken on the Azure Managed Application itself. You can combine this with a ViewDefinition to provide buttons and UI on the Managed Application that can invoke these actions, such as restarting or stopping the app.

o   A tutorial of Custom Providers and View Definitions: [Tutorial: Create managed application with custom actions and resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/tutorial-create-managed-app-with-custom-provider?tabs=azurecli-interactive)

o   Overview of ViewDefinition and what is possible with it today: [Concept: ViewDefinition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/managed-applications/concepts-view-definition)

o   All documentation for Azure Custom Providers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/custom-providers/overview